# How to open port in ExpressJS, unable to run the port?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

**Here is my code.**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');


var app = express();

app.listen(9000, function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
});
```

Dependencies are also added.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
  },
```

While running node app it should run the port, so I can open it witih browser, instead of showing the result in the command like, ref to Screen Shoot.
[Terminal Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAtrY.png)

Comment: everything is fine. Your app IS listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is running, just open `http://localhost:9000`. You will see `Cannot get /` response.